# EvenListener in setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, event-listener

Everything is working except addEventListener

```
const attack1Animation = [
        { transform:'rotate(0deg)' },
        { transform:'translate(-67%, 320%) rotate(90deg)'}
    ];
```

```
let weapon1 = document.getElementById('weapon1');
```

```
var attack1 = setInterval(function(){
        weapon1.style.visibility = "visible";
        weapon1.animate(attack1Animation, attackTiming);
        weapon1.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
            console.log("Animation ended");
          });
    }, 10000/unit1.attack_speed);
```

i can't unterstand why it's not working, i don't have any warnings or errors in console, i tried change it to something like this:

```
var attack1 = setInterval(function(){
        weapon1.style.visibility = "visible";
        weapon1.animate(attack1Animation, attackTiming);
        weapon1.onanimationend = () => {
            console.log("Animation ended");
          });
    }, 10000/unit1.attack_speed)
```

but result is the same

Comment: so you don't even get `console.log("Animation ended");` happening? and when you say "it isn't working", what isn't working? no animation at all? only part of the animation?

Comment: Unfortunately not even that

Comment: that would suggest `animationend` event isn't firing

Comment: i thought maybe it is not working beacuse of interval, i though interval ends and it's not listening anymore, but when i use it outside interval the result is still the same :c

Comment: perhaps you should use the `Animation` object returned by `.animate` - the object has a property called `finished` which is a Promise that resolves when the animation finishes - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation)

Comment: probably it's not firing, but i can't unterstand why :/

Comment: read what [element.animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) returns and [how to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation)

Comment: You shouldn't use `addEventListener()` repeatedly, since you're never removing the old listener.

Comment: ok, i used 
let animation1 = weapon1.animate(attack1Animation, attackTiming);
        animation1.onfinish 
and it worked! :D
thank you for all advices

Comment: @JaromandaX those links u send me were really helpfull

Comment: @Barmar i implemented AbortController, hope this is what u meant